# How to show error messages in HTML page in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have following login form (login.php) in which I am asking for username and password.

```
<form action="processlogin.php" method="post">            
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">                                
</form>
```

Following is the code snippet from my processlogin.php file

```
if(!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"])
{
    $msg = "You left one or more of the required fields.";
    echo $msg;
    //header("Location:http://localhost/login.php");
}
```

This code checks whether all the mandatory fields are filled on not. If not, it shows the error message.

Till now everything is fine.

My problem is that, error message is shown in plain white page. I want to show it above the login form in login.php file. How should I change my code to get
my functionality.

Comment: Use javascript or jquery instead of using php for validations

Comment: I would agree to use something like jQuery AJAX and get a JSON return that you can pass the error message in. It takes a little getting used to at first but can save you a bunch of headaches around this. Another option if you dont want to use javascript is to pass the error message in a session variable and do an isset($_SESSION['my_var']) ? $_SESSION['my_var'] : ""; on it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would prefer Jquery Validation or Ajax based Authentication. But still you can do it this way:

Put your Error Message in Session like this :

```
$_SESSION['Error'] = "You left one or more of the required fields.";
```

Than simple show it like this:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['Error']) )
{
        echo $_SESSION['Error'];

        unset($_SESSION['Error']);

}
```

In this case you can assign multiple messages in different Operations.

Comment: i dont' understand where your second code snippet is to be placed

Answer (score 3):

```
header("Location:http://localhost/login.php?x=1")
```

In the login.php

```
if(isset($_GET('x'))){
//your html for error message
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use these functions:

```
<?php
session_start();
define(FLASH_PREFIX,'Flash_')

function set_flash($key,$val){
    $_SESSION[FLASH_PREFIX.$key]=$val;
}

function is_flash($key){
    return array_key_exits(FLASH_PREFIX.$key,$_SESSION);
}
function get_flash($key){
    return $_SESSION[FLASH_PREFIX.$key];
}
function pop_flash($key){
    $ret=$_SESSION[FLASH_PREFIX.$key];
    unset($_SESSION[FLASH_PREFIX.$key]);
    return $ret;
}
?>
```

And when you want to send a message to another page use

```
set_flash('err_msg','one field is empty');
header('location: another.php');
exit();
```

another.php

```
<html>
.
.
.
<body>
<?php if(is_flash('err_msg')){?>
<span class="err_msg"><?php echo pop_flash('err_msg'); ?></span>
<?php } ?>
.
.
.
</body></html>
```

Comment: This is fine but you are making it way complex. Code must be simpler an easy to manage.

Comment: thanks for your attention but I think somplex things are needed when the scale is growing.(-:

Comment: i dont understand where the condition test for the form fields is in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can display the message in table or span above the form.

```
    <span>
    <?php if(isset($_REQUEST[$msg]))
    echo $msg;
    ?>
    </span>
    <form>
    </form>
```

And also don't echo $msg in the form's action page.

Answer (score 1):

Use only one page (your `login.php`) to display the form and also to validate its data if sent. So you don't need any $_SESSION variables and you have all in one and the same file which belongs together.

```
<?php

$msg = null;

if(isset($_GET['send'])) {
    if(!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"]){
        $msg = "You left one or more of the required fields.";

        //header("Location:http://localhost/login.php");
    }
}

?>

<?php echo ($msg !== null)?'<p>ERROR: ' . $msg . '</p>':null; ?>

<form action="?send" method="post">            
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">                                
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**html:**

```
<form action="processlogin.php" method="post">            
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login"> 
<span>
 <?php if(isset($_GET['msg']))
  echo $_GET['msg'];
  ?>
</span>                               
</form>
```

**php:**

```
if(!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"])
{
$msg = "You left one or more of the required fields.";
header("Location:http://localhost/login.php?msg=$msg");
}
```

Comment: what if $_GET['msg'] contains any special chars? please check Chinnu R's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps you,

In processlogin.php,

```
        if(!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"])
            {
                $msg = "You left one or more of the required fields.";
                $msgEncoded = base64_encode($msg);
                header("location:login.php?msg=".$msgEncoded);
            }
```

in login.php file,

```
          $msg = base64_decode($_GET['msg']);
            if(isset($_GET['msg'])){

                if($msg!=""){
                    echo $msg;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
if(!$_POST["username"] || !$_POST["password"])
{
    $msg = "You left one or more of the required fields.";
    echo $msg;
    //header("Location:http://localhost/login.php");
}
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">            
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">                                
</form>
```